# Regular update broke initramfs on Elementary OS 6

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, initramfs, elementary-os, proprietary-drivers

NOTE:

- I have above average Linux experience but not an elite.
- I have an Nvidia GTX 1650 laptop card.
- I use Linux XanMod CacULE kernel.
- I use the latest Mesa and Nvidia drivers from

  - http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu and
  - http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu

I installed Elementary OS two months ago and have not run into any issues since then.

`systemctl --failed` and `journalctl -p 3 -b` were fine as I check them regularly. All updates have been smooth since install.

---

I use a simple apt-fast script to update my system. it is located in `/usr/bin/`.

Here it is

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
sudo apt-fast clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-fast autoclean
sudo apt-fast update
echo
echo
echo "Packages that will be updated:"
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
sudo apt list --upgradable -a
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
echo
echo
sudo apt-fast upgrade -y
sudo apt-fast full-upgrade -y
sudo apt-fast autoremove --purge --auto-remove -y
sudo apt-fast clean
sudo flatpak update
```

This was what happened during the update:
https://pastebin.com/xh4EZXT5

I found out something went wrong.

So I ran

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

The error persists.
I googled the error and tried to reinstall `initramfs-tools`.

I removed it using:

```
sudo apt remove initramfs-tools
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then I ran `sudo apt install initramfs-tools` but still I get the error.

Now I am getting this

```
~ ❯❯❯ sudo apt-get install -f initramfs-tools

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
initramfs-tools is already the newest version (0.136ubuntu6.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.14.15-xanmod1-cacule
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/data-swap)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.14.15-xanmod1-cacule with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
~ ❯❯❯ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.14.15-xanmod1-cacule
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/data-swap)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.14.15-xanmod1-cacule with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
```

```
~ ❯❯❯ sudo journalctl -p 3 -b
-- Logs begin at Fri 2021-10-22 13:47:38 IST, end at Sat 2021-10-30 16:55:55 IST. --
Oct 30 11:15:51 Strix kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Oct 30 11:15:51 Strix kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_GPE._E4A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210604/dswload2-326)
Oct 30 11:15:51 Strix kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210604/psobject-220)
Oct 30 11:15:51 Strix kernel: 
Oct 30 11:15:55 Strix lightdm[2302]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 11:15:55 Strix lightdm[2302]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Oct 30 11:15:55 Strix lightdm[2302]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 11:15:55 Strix lightdm[2302]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Oct 30 11:15:56 Strix systemd[2306]: Failed to start Portal service (GTK+/GNOME implementation).
Oct 30 11:15:56 Strix lightdm[2496]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 11:15:56 Strix lightdm[2496]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Oct 30 11:15:56 Strix lightdm[2496]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 11:15:56 Strix lightdm[2496]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Oct 30 11:15:56 Strix lightdm[2521]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 11:15:56 Strix lightdm[2521]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Oct 30 11:15:56 Strix lightdm[2521]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 11:15:56 Strix lightdm[2521]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Oct 30 11:16:06 Strix lightdm[2521]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Oct 30 16:17:56 Strix systemd[1]: Failed to start Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages.
Oct 30 16:17:56 Strix kernel: [drm:drm_new_set_master [drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Oct 30 16:17:56 Strix kernel: [drm:drm_new_set_master [drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Oct 30 16:18:00 Strix lightdm[36108]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 16:18:00 Strix lightdm[36108]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Oct 30 16:18:00 Strix lightdm[36108]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 16:18:00 Strix lightdm[36108]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Oct 30 16:18:00 Strix bluetoothd[851]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
Oct 30 16:18:00 Strix bluetoothd[851]: RFCOMM server failed for :1.120/Profile/HSPHSProfile/00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
Oct 30 16:18:01 Strix systemd[36112]: Failed to start Portal service (GTK+/GNOME implementation).
Oct 30 16:18:01 Strix lightdm[36277]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 16:18:01 Strix lightdm[36277]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Oct 30 16:18:01 Strix lightdm[36277]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 16:18:01 Strix lightdm[36277]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Oct 30 16:18:01 Strix lightdm[36318]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 16:18:01 Strix lightdm[36318]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Oct 30 16:18:01 Strix lightdm[36318]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 30 16:18:01 Strix lightdm[36318]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Oct 30 16:18:09 Strix lightdm[36318]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Oct 30 16:18:10 Strix kernel: [drm:drm_new_set_master [drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Oct 30 16:18:10 Strix kernel: [drm:drm_new_set_master [drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Oct 30 16:18:10 Strix kernel: [drm:drm_new_set_master [drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Oct 30 16:18:10 Strix kernel: [drm:drm_new_set_master [drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Oct 30 16:54:37 Strix systemd[1]: Failed to start Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages.
Oct 30 16:54:52 Strix systemd[1]: Failed to start Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages.
Oct 30 16:55:00 Strix systemd[1]: Failed to start Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages.
```

```
~ ❯❯❯ systemctl --failed
  UNIT                 LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                           
● ua-messaging.service loaded failed failed Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed.
~ ❯❯❯ sudo systemctl restart ua-messaging.service
Job for ua-messaging.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ua-messaging.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
~ ❯❯❯ sudo systemctl start ua-messaging.service
Job for ua-messaging.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ua-messaging.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

My preferable resolution would be to remove the postinstall script that is causing the problem. Otherwise I won't prefer to remove the PPA for Mesa and Nvidia.

My computer is still able to reboot, but I am not able to use APT package manager. I need to install `initramfs-tools` which I removed following a solution on similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is really easy to solve

Solution with explanation:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/
ls -al
#list packages installed

sudo rm -rf initramfs-tools*
#removes the problem files

sudo apt update 
#updates software cache 

sudo apt --fix-broken install
#looks for other problems and solve it 

sudo apt install initramfs-tools*
#recovers problems packages .
```

Correct script will be :

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
echo
echo
echo "Packages that will be updated:"
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
sudo apt list --upgradable -a
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
echo
echo
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get full-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get autoremove  -y
sudo apt-get clean
```

Use apt-get or aptitude -f instead of apt-fast

```
apt-get
#stable

apt-fast
#unstable but fast

aptitude -f
#best and safe and fix all the problems .

--purge 
#without specification can sometimes delete important files
```

### If this didn't worked then post the output of each command I told you to do , specially `apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: The apt error is gone but now I have ran into a bigger problem after following the solution. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675486/elementary-os-6-not-booting-please-help

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` fails to use `lz4`. I guess you should install it (`apt install lz4`).

But a better idea seems to check `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` and the `COMPRESS` option. I have the following comment :

```
# COMPRESS: [ gzip | bzip2 | lz4 | lzma | lzop | xz ]
```

Use `gzip`. Grub has only the modules gz, lzop, xz and my `grub.cfg` loads only `gzip` (Excepted with a xen platform where lzop and xz are also loaded).

Also, just have a look in your `/boot` directory : if there are no initrd files, you don’t need `initramfs-tools`

Comment: It doesn't look like a grub or initramfs problem it is an apt problem

Comment: You get an error because the `initramfs-tools` tried to compress with `lz4`. If you fix it making such a compression possible, you may have an other issue if your system can’t handle such a compression.